# What roles do cyclooxygenase, lipoxygenase, and epoxygenase have in signal transduction?

Tags: cell-biology

Besides oxidizing fatty acids to form prostglandins, leukotrienes, and epoxides, what other roles do cyclooxygenase, lipoxygenase, and epoxygenase have in signal transduction?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Do you have any preliminary ideas?

Comment: No. I was reading about how these enzymes oxidize fatty acids in my textbook, but I was curious to know if they had any other important functions in signal transduction. I honestly don't have much of an idea on what else they could possibly do, since I have no previous knowledge on these particular enzymes.

Comment: Fair enought. The reason I asked was because your Q seemed to fall under our [homework policy](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/questions/266/homework-policy-for-faq). Do you have any special reason to believe that these enzymes have other roles?

Answer (score 2):

I just took a quick look.

These classes of enzymes are important to a family of lipid based molecules which perform intra and intercellular signalling with a lot of medical importance.

[Epoxygenases can create epoxides of arachidonic acid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxygenase),  which can modulate cell proliferation.  Arachidonic acid is a well known second messenger in many tissues in the cell, so these enzymes clearly would affect many signalling pathways.

Cyclooxygenases (COX) enzymes are such [important mediators of inflammation signalling that they are the primary targets of aspirin and other Non steroidal anti-inflammatory drugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclooxygenase).

Lipoxygenases oxygenate compounds such as prostaglandins which are downstream from aranchidonic acid (as does COX).